# Unable to install Appium version 2.0 beta

Tags: appium

I'm trying to install Appium 2.0 beta version https://applitools.com/blog/appium-2-0-beta/ I'm entering command "npm install -g appium@next" and I'm seeing Appium version 1.22.3 this is preventing me from moving on and installing Appium Drivers. Please help?

[image: Terminal Photo]

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem. I have to close the Appium server first before running npm install -g appium@next.